# ambiguous redirect - file gets created

Tags: shell

I get an ambiguous redirect message even though the output file gets created.

my sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

# you can use read or VAR="$1" to setup these variables
SERVER_IP=
SERVER_PORT=
LANGUAGE_URL=
PROJECT_NAME=

while read f1 
 do 
OUTPUTFIL=$f1

{
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"Shift-JIS\"?>"
    echo "<flash_cfg>"
    echo "<server ip=\"${SERVER_IP}\" port=\"${SERVER_PORT}\"/>"
    echo "<language_url>${LANGUAGE_URL}</language_url>"
    echo "<project_name>${PROJECT_NAME}</project_name>"
    echo "</flash_cfg>"
} > ${OUTPUTFIL}

 done < file
```

content of "file

```
out.xml
```

while running

```
:~/Documents$ bash shell.sh
shell.sh: line 22: ${OUTPUTFIL}: ambiguous redirect
```

The file out.xml is created however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No contradiction there, you have a loop.

So first you read a valid filename (`out.xml`), and create a file, then you're reading an invalid one, which creates the error message.

Example (you have an empty line in the input):

```
f=""
echo "Q" > ${f}
-bash: ${f}: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `cat` to simplify the code--see if this works any better:

```
while read f1 
do 
cat <<EOF >"$f1"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift-JIS"?>
<flash_cfg>
<server ip="${SERVER_IP}" port="${SERVER_PORT}"/>
<language_url>${LANGUAGE_URL}</language_url>
<project_name>${PROJECT_NAME}</project_name>
</flash_cfg>
EOF
done < file
```

That's known as a "here document" and lets you avoid all those echo's and quoting.

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't address the actual question.